# I can't open my Minecraft maps even though they exist

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have something strange and can't figure it out by myself. I have 2 maps in my saves that I can't open. I have played on them, but one time they where gone so I searched for them in the Minecraft folder, and found them. There was nothing strange with them, so I don't really get it. Does anybody have an idea about what's wrong?

EDIT:
Mrlemon is right, I found them in the map but can't open them in Minecraft itself. I compared the 2 maps with one that I can open in Minecraft (and see) but don't see a difference in between those. Here are some screenshots of it.

My world:
[image]

World that I can't see:
[image]

Comment: What's really the question here? they went missing and you found them. Do you wanna know why they went missing?

Comment: @Michel I think he wants to say he found the files in the savegame folder, but still couldn't access the saves in game.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague... Because there are many reasons why your world is not appearing. Could it be either a: missing level.dat file, or perhaps your world is corrupted or it is in a format that is too old (before the [Anvil File Format](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Anvil_file_format)) or that your world is not even a Minecraft world... Or it might be something not listed here.

Comment: In the debug tab in the launcher it will give you an indication as it loads in world saves. Does yours display this information, and is there an error listed there?

If you can't find the debug console, then this information should be available in the log files produced in your minecraft folder.

Comment: if u mean the launcher for minecraft, it only says that iam logging in and that my playerdata is found but nothing more..

Comment: Which version of Minecraft was the map created with? And does it require any mods?

Answer (score 2):

You can try renaming `level.dat` to `level.dat.bck` and `level.dat_old` to `level.dat`. If your problem is a level.dat corruption (likely if the world doesn't even show up), this should fix it at the cost of losing a bit of progress (that is, your position and inventory will be rolled back to a moment earlier).

Comment: Ehm, how do i change it back into a previous version?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: oh i see a diffrents now between the both, the one who does not work has has the two files as an text document and the other who does work has it as an application/gzip how can i change the other one?

Comment: If you don't have level_old.dat, short of fixing it yourself with an NBT editor, you're out of luck...